# how to change database tables module to make SQL selecting faster?

Tags: sql

I'm making a website where I display *questions* and *answers* asked by *users*.

My problem is every time I want to display a *question* I have to select the *question* & the *user* & *sum of votes* & userid who voted (to check if the logged in user already voted)

So I'm using *4 queries* to get the question and user and number of votes & check if question has already been liked/disliked
and I still need to add answers too so that's 4 more queries for each answer. Is there a way to speed it up?

PS: I'm using php & mysqli to display data

I chose my sql tables to be :

```
question {
 id (primary key),
 title,
 date,
 user_id (foreign key) (added index) (to see who asked the question)
}

vote {
 id (primary key),
 type (like(=1) or dislike(=-1)),
 user_id (to see which user voted),
 question_id (foreign key) (added index)
}

user{
 id (primary key),
 username,
 password
}
```

Is there a way to adjust my tables for better speed?

Comment: Do it in one run using `JOIN`s?

Comment: Fix the queries! It can be done in one!!

Comment: "Is there a way to speed it up?" Is it actually slow? Why do you need to speed it up?

Comment: What is your DBMS? Please always tag SQL questions with the DBMS you are using.

Comment: @Dharman: With a website accessing data from a database you want to avoid round trips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to change your tables.

Join the aggregated votes to your question table. You can use conditional aggregation to see whether the user voted, too.

```
select *
from question q
left join
(
  select
    question_id,
    sum(type) as cumulated_vote,
    sum(when user_id = current_user then type end) as own_vote
  from vote
  group by question_id
) v on v.question_id = q.id
```

Replace `current_user` with the variable or function your DBMS uses to show the current user.